# i am trying to implement firebase pagination , but is keeps adding the last child twice

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

**I am calling this method when the user scrolls to the last position
but methods adding the last child twice, like if I have "a,b,c,d,e" , The user will see "a,b,b,c,d,d,e,e,e,e,e......."
I tried every tutorial, everyone doing it this way.**

```
 void getAllNotification(String lastKey){
        Query query;
        if(lastKey==null){
            query=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("test").orderByKey().limitToFirst(2);
        }else {
            query=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("test").orderByKey().startAt(lastKey).limitToFirst(2);
        }
        query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                for (DataSnapshot snapshot:dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    arrayList.add(snapshot);
                    this.lastKey=snapshot.getKey();
                    Log.d("Notification", "onDataChange: "+snapshot.toString());
                }
                notificationAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) { }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Use FirebaseRecyclerAdapter for this - https://medium.com/android-grid/how-to-use-firebaserecycleradpater-with-latest-firebase-dependencies-in-android-aff7a33adb8b

Comment: I want to add child when user scroll, I don't think there is something to do with Firebase Adapter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `startAt(key)`, the value for `key` is included in the returned results. Because we are using `orderByKey()` and each key is unique, to "start after" the value of `key`, you can append a space to it. This is because keys are sorted [lexicographically](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order) and a space, character `\u0020`, is the character with the lowest unicode codepoint that is permitted in a key name. Characters 0-31 (`\u0000`-`\u001F`) are [not permitted](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data#how_data_is_structured_its_a_json_tree). Cloud Firestore introduced `startAfter()` to make this more intuitive.

So to apply this change to your code, you can use:

```js
void getAllNotification(String lastKey){
    Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("test").orderByKey().limitToFirst(2);

    if (lastKey != null) {
      query = query.startAt(lastKey + " "); // start at lastKey, but exclude it from results (because of orderByKey())
    }

    query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.hasChildren()) {
              // handle no data or no more data
              return;
            }

            for (DataSnapshot snapshot:dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                arrayList.add(snapshot);
                this.lastKey=snapshot.getKey(); // ??
                Log.d("Notification", "onDataChange - new data: "+snapshot.toString());
            }

            notificationAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
          // TODO: Log errors
        }
    });
}
```

In your `onDataChange` handler, you use `this.lastKey=snapshot.getKey();` but what `this` represents is unclear and thus I recommend changing it to `component`/`parent` or something else that makes it clearer.

Comment: I'd recommend against adding a space, as there may be results with the same value for the sort-property, and you'd be skipping those. So while this approach may work in certain scenarios, it's not a good general solution. The idiomatic way to deal with this is to skip the overlapping/anchor node when processing one of the pages.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen You're right that I should clarify that this is specifically for `startAt()` when using `orderByKey()` which are unique by the nature that they are keys.

Answer (score 0):

onDataChange is called twice in case you have enabled offline persistence. 
check if you have this maybe :

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
```

from:[Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities#section-disk-persistence)

Comment: did you remove the Listener?